# Proc IML with sas

Tags: sas

I have the following table :

```
WEIGHT  DATE 1/1/11    1/2/11   1/3/11 ... 1/12/11 
NAME
NICK            70 kg       .      72kg       .
JOHN            60 kg      63 kg    .        60 kg
MIKE            50kg       51kg    50kg       . 
BOB             75kg        .       .         .
...
```

And I would like to fill in the missing values '.' with the previsous declaration .

For example for NICK I would get :

```
WEIGHT  DATE 1/1/11    1/2/11   1/3/11 ... 1/12/11 
NAME
NICK        70 kg       70kg      72kg       72kg
```

I'm pretty new to sas and I don't have a clue on how to do it. For the time being, my idea would be  to use a proc IML to read each line as an array and work on it, but I've never used such a proc.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PROC IML. You can do this with arrays and the first and last statements and probably a lag statement as well.

I am not expert on the data step, but searching SAS-L will find something. I know this problem has been solved by Ron Cody in his book on Longitudinal Data in SAS, but I don't have access to that book right now.

Comment: Thx a lot, it works fine with array, but I'm having a new issue now. I don't know how to define my array based on date ? Do you have an idea on how to do that ? for the moment I changed the name of the column to COL1 ... COL12 and wrote array[12] COL1-COL12 .

Comment: Actually I find a solution. Thanks again.